Method defined in Custom Repository Implementation is not being recognized (Property Reference Exception)
This question is related to Custom Repository Implementation
I have created a custom repo
public interface CustomTransactionRepo<TEntity> {
    List<TEntity> basicSearch(String searchQuery, String searchColumn, Class<TEntity> collectionType);
}

Its implementation:
@Repository
public class CustomTransactionRepoImpl<TEntity> implements CustomTransactionRepo<TEntity> {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<TEntity> basicSearch(String searchQuery, String searchColumn, Class<TEntity> en) {
        var query = new Query();
        var criteria = new ArrayList<Criteria>();
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(searchQuery)) {
            criteria.add(Criteria.where(searchColumn)
                                 .regex(searchQuery, "i"));
        }
        query.addCriteria(new Criteria().andOperator(criteria.toArray(new Criteria[0])));

        var simRecords = mongoTemplate.find(query, en);
        return simRecords;
    }
}

I have a BaseJPA repo that extends my CustomRepo (CustomTransactionRepo) and MongoRepository
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseJpaRepo<TEntity> extends CustomTransactionRepo<TEntity>, MongoRepository<TEntity, String> {
}

and finally MyRepository (SimRecordRepository) that just only need to extend BaseJpaRepo
@Repository
public interface SimRecordRepository extends BaseJpaRepo<SimRecord> {
    
}

and I am calling this repo from my service layer:
@Service
public class TransactionServiceImpl implements TransactionService {

    @Autowired
    private SimRecordRepository repo;

    @Override
    public List<SimRecord> basicSearch(String searchQuery, String searchColumn) {
        return repo.basicSearch(searchQuery, searchColumn, SimRecord.class);
    }
}

My Entity SimRecord:
@Document(collection = "sim_record")
public class SimRecord {
    private String id;
    private String system;
    private String entity;
    @Field("business_ref")
    private String businessRef;
    private String recordSetId;
    private Object payload;
    private String payloadType;
    private Object canonical;
    private String canonicalType;
    private String processingStatus;
    private String recordStatus;
    private String resultType;
    private String classValue;
// Getters and Setters

Now while running the build i am getting the exception:
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'basicSearch' found for type 'SimRecord'

I am unsure what else need to done.
Note
My Application works well when I remove the BaseJpaRepo and instead make SimRecordRepository directly extend CustomTransactionRepo and MongoRepository. like this:
@Repository
public interface SimRecordRepository extends MongoRepository<SimRecord, String>, CustomTransactionRepo<SimRecord> {

}

What i expected was that the i should be able to call the method basicSarch() but instead got that propertyReference Exception

The issue you're encountering is likely due to the way Spring Data JPA and MongoDB handle the extension and composition of repositories. The root cause can be traced to the fact that Spring Data might not be able to correctly detect the custom implementation when it is extended through an intermediate base repository interface (BaseJpaRepo in this case).
When you use a direct extension of MongoRepository and CustomTransactionRepo, Spring Data can easily find and use the custom implementation. However, adding an additional layer with BaseJpaRepo introduces complexity that can confuse the repository factory.
Spring Data Repository Detection:
Spring Data repositories use specific naming conventions and rules to detect custom repository implementations. The BaseJpaRepo interface adds an additional layer that might not be properly scanned and processed by Spring Data.
Implementation Naming and Structure:
Spring Data requires custom implementations to be named with Impl suffix and placed correctly within the package structure.
Steps to Resolve -->
Direct Extension of Repositories:
If direct extension works, it suggests that Spring Data can correctly wire the custom implementation without the intermediate interface. Stick to the working structure if it suits your design.
Ensure Proper Package Scanning:
Verify that the package scanning is correctly configured to include all relevant packages where your repositories and their implementations reside.
Custom Implementation Naming:
Ensure the naming of the custom implementation follows Spring's conventions and it is placed in the correct package.

I am trying to create sort of a framework so that My Client code does not need to extends these two repos again and again. Hence it does not suit my design
and I am following the basic project hierarchy structure that gets followed.

Additionally, MongoRepository itself extends multiple Fragment Repos such as ListCrudRepository, ListPagingAndSortingRepository and QueryByExampleExecutor, so in a way MongoRepository is also an intermediary layer. How is it able to call all the methods defined in the fragment repos?
